# How does armor work in Shogun 2: Total War?

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

I've played Shogun 2 for a while now, and something I still don't understand is armor. The unit with the most notable armor is the [Naginata Samurai](http://www.totalwars.ru/encyclopedia/units/inf_heavy_naginata_samurai.html) with 9. Compare that to a [Yari Ashigaru](http://www.totalwars.ru/encyclopedia/units/inf_spear_yari_ashigaru.html) that has 2 armor, and it seems like there's a huge difference. I can see the number value of unit armor, but I don't understand is how that factors into combat. Does armor reduce the damage done by arrows? Does armor just give an increased dodge chance?

I think these might be questions of how combat is calculated by the game engine and not just of armor, but armor is my real concern. I can immediately see the effects of increased attack or morale, but not as much by increased armor.

**How does armor affect the survivability of a unit?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this forum post](http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?437418-The-Armor-stat-what-does-it-do&p=9237658&viewfull=1#post9237658), but I'm not sure if it is true.

Melee damage is calculated as:

(Attack power+Charge bonus *if applicable*) - (melee defense+**armor**+special ability *if applicable*+ any other bonus *if applicable*).

Ranged damage is calculated as:

(Ranged attack power+accuracy+reloading skill) - (**armor**+formation if applicable)

Melee makes sense, but ranged is still unclear to me. If you look on the stats sheet for a ranged unit like [Bow Warrior Monks](http://www.totalwars.ru/encyclopedia/units/inf_missile_bow_warrior_monks.html), there is no attribute for "Ranged attack power" (*range* is how far the unit can shoot). Can anyone confirm the validity of these formulas?

**Armor subtracts from attack power and other bonuses when damage is calculated.**